# I am working in react native and while using react-native-firebase APNS token is getting null

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using react-native-firebase 5.6.0 with react-native 0.64.0 and react 17.0.1. I want to get APNS token in iOS device which I am checking in real device still I am getting APNS token as null in response.
Following is my react native code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeModules, Platform, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {
    shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector,
} from 'react-redux';

import * as Routes from 'constants/routes';
import { sentryCapture } from 'utils/errorUtils';
import NotificationPermission from 'screens/Shared/NotificationPermission';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { actions as ProfileActions } from 'store/modules/profile';
import { selectors as AuthSelectors } from 'store/modules/auth';
import AppBottomTabNavigator from './AppBottomTabNavigator';

const AppContainer = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // const router = useRoute();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const [hasNotificationPermission, setHasNotificationPermission] = useState(true);
    const [ignoreNotificationPermission, setIgnoreNotificationPermission] = useState(false);

    const workerId = useSelector(AuthSelectors.accountId, shallowEqual);

    const getAPNSToken = async () => {
        try {
            await firebase.messaging().ios.registerForRemoteNotifications();
            return firebase.messaging().ios.getAPNSToken();
        } catch (e) {
            sentryCapture('Failed to get an APNS token', {
                extra: { error: e },
            });
        }
    };

    const getToken = async () => {
        try {
            const [savedTokens, fcmToken] = await Promise.all([
                dispatch(ProfileActions.fetchNotificationEndpoints()),
                firebase.messaging().getToken(),
            ]);

            if (fcmToken) {
                let currentToken = fcmToken;
                if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                    currentToken = await getAPNSToken();
                }

                if (currentToken && !savedTokens.includes(currentToken)) {
                    dispatch(ProfileActions.registerNotificationEndpoint(currentToken));
                }
            }
        } catch { }
    };

    const checkPermission = async () => {
        const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
        if (enabled) {
            getToken();
        } else {
            setHasNotificationPermission(false);
        }
    };

    const handleNotificationOpen = (notificationOpen) => {
        const {
            notification: { data },
        } = notificationOpen;

        if (data) {
            if (data.jobId) {
                const jobId = parseInt(data.jobId, 10);
                navigation.navigate(Routes.JobDetails, { jobId });
            } else if (data.positionId) {
                const positionId = parseInt(data.positionId, 10);
                navigation.navigate(Routes.PositionDetails, { positionId, isActive: true });
            }
        }

        firebase
            .notifications()
            .removeDeliveredNotification(notificationOpen.notification.notificationId);
    };

    const handleInitialNotification = async (notificationOpen) => {
        try {
            const lastInitialNotificationId = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
                'lastInitialNotificationId',
            );

            if (
                lastInitialNotificationId !== null
                && lastInitialNotificationId === notificationOpen.notification.notificationId
            ) {
                return;
            }

            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                'lastInitialNotificationId',
                String(notificationOpen.notification.notificationId),
            );

            handleNotificationOpen(notificationOpen);
        } catch (e) {
            // don't mind, this is a problem only if the current RN instance has been reloaded by a CP mandatory update
        }
    };

    const handleIgnoreNotificationPermission = () => {
        setIgnoreNotificationPermission(true);
    };

    const handleRequestNotificationPermission = async () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            NativeModules.OpenNotification.open();
            setHasNotificationPermission(true);
        } else {
            try {
                await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
                getToken();
            } catch (error) {
                Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
            } finally {
                setHasNotificationPermission(true);
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
            'new_jobs',
            'New jobs',
            firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
        );
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
        checkPermission();
        // createNotificationListeners();

        const removeNotificationListener = firebase
            .notifications()
            .onNotification((notification) => {
                notification.android.setChannelId('new_jobs').setSound('default');
                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
            });

        const removeNotificationOpenedListener = firebase
            .notifications()
            .onNotificationOpened(handleNotificationOpen);

        const removeMessageListener = firebase
            .notifications()
            .getInitialNotification()
            .then(handleInitialNotification);

        firebase.analytics().setUserId(workerId);

        return () => {
            removeNotificationListener();
            removeMessageListener();
            removeNotificationOpenedListener();
        };
    }, []);

    if (!hasNotificationPermission && !ignoreNotificationPermission) {
        return (
            <NotificationPermission
                onSkip={handleIgnoreNotificationPermission}
                onAccept={handleRequestNotificationPermission}
            />
        );
    }

    return <AppBottomTabNavigator />;
};

export default AppContainer;
```

Following is the AppDelegate.m code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import Firebase;
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif
  [FIRApp configure];
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"grizzlyforce"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

I have spend couple of week on this issue but still unable to find the exact issue
I have all the procedure of making APNs certificate changes in Info.plist file made push notification enable in build settings as well as in developer account of our registered application still unable to solve this issue